# Can a SharePoint Site Top Level Collection have both publishing and team sites active?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can a SharePoint Site Top Level Collection have both publishing and team sites active? On the top level site I  have:

·         Server Enterprise Site Collection features,

·         SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure,

·         SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection

Can these features be active on one top level site at the same time?

The reason I ask is because an some point my new subsite will not create new pages and when I transferred some pages to new subsites they won’t display the Page Content regions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be active at the same time on the root level site collections, but you can disable any if you are not using them or no more needed.

Please read below what each feature do:

**SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features**

> Enables the following services: InfoPath Forms Services, Visio Services,
>   Access Services, Excel Services

**Applies** only to the SharePoint Server Enterprise License

**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**

> Enables a set of Web Content Management functionality such as Team
>   Sites and Public-facing websites. This includes centralized libraries,
>   content types, master pages, and page layouts. Enables page scheduling
>   and other publishing functionality for a site collection.

**Applies** None

**SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features**

> Enables the following services: User Profile Service, Search Service

**Applies** only to the SharePoint Server Standard License

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-HA102772720.aspx